# Expressjs: Processing errors from DB operations (next is undefined)

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, mongoose-schema

I am trying to develop a flow-pattern to handle errors encountered when trying to perform database operations.  I am a little lost, but I think I am pretty close to figuring it out.  This is the example I have been trying to emulate:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/65199/mongoose-promise-error-handling

Here is my function from the mongoose schema:

```
exports.deleteAttorney = function (id, cb) {  <-- I am not using cb.  Do I need it?

    let query = {
        _id: "6a34056376bbd68eb1ccdf11"
    };

    Firm.Firm.findOne( query, "attorneys", function (err, firm) {

        if (err || !firm) {
            return next( err || new Error("deleteAttorney() could not retrieve the firm's attorneys.") );
        }

        firm.attorneys.id(id).remove();

        firm.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Here is where I call it from within the router:

```
router.post('/delete', function(req, res) {

    Attorney.deleteAttorney(req.query._id, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);  <-- I intend to put some user-friendly messaging here
        }

        res.redirect('/attorneys/manage');
    });

});
```

"next" is undefined.  I don't fully understand how to use it, and I am not sure whether it should be used at all.

What I want is an attempt to get the data.  After the attempt is made (whether successful or not), I want the callback as shown to run. From within model's method, it looks like I need to return any errors to the callback, but I am not sure how.

If I am using a bad approach, how should it be done?

## **Edit**

Josh's answer helped confirm my suspicion about replacing next() with cb().  Here is the revised code.  It works.  Does this look like good practice?  If so, I will use this same pattern for all my DB operations.  I don't want to jump in to the rest of them until I settle on this one.

```
exports.deleteAttorney = function (id, cb) {

    let query = {
        _id: "6a34056376bbd68eb1ccdf11"
    };

    Firm.Firm.findOne( query, "attorneys", function (err, firm) {

        if (err || !firm) {
            cb( err || new Error("deleteAttorney() could not retrieve the firm's attorneys.") );
            return;
        }

        firm.attorneys.id(id).remove();

        firm.save(function (err, firm, numAffected) {
            cb(err, firm, numAffected);
            return;
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to call, when you call `next` is really `cb`. So rename either of them. Also, you shouldn't only call `next` if an error occurred, but also if your operation was successful. Otherwise, your redirect will never be called.

I think you should spend some time understanding callbacks, which are fundamental to Node.js and also, look at the error first pattern. Maybe this [article](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/) can help you.

Comment: Thanks, Josh.  I have been reading up quite a bit, and this post was to try to put it all in focus.  Can you look at my edit and provide some input?

Comment: It looks okay. You could also write `firm.save(cb)` because you don't change any argument.